# Variable from a for loop not showing in another loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

I've been practicing webscraping with the nba.com playerlist, but I've ran into a problem where a link that I scraped in one for loop does not appear when I call on it in another for loop.

I have already tried to make more variables in both the original for loop and the for loop I want the variable to show up in, but it does not appear.  I am trying to use the link that I scraped (it is not the full link but rather the end part of the link which I'm trying to combine with the base of the link).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
class Player():
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.link = ""
        self.PPG = ""
        self.RPG = ""
def get_player_list():
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    browser.get('https://stats.nba.com/players/list/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    browser.quit()
    names = soup.find('div',class_='stats-player-list players-list')
    player_list = []



for name in names.find_all('a'):
        new_play = Player()
        new_play.name = name.text
        new_play.link = name["href"]
        player_list.append(new_play)

    for one_player in player_list:
        print (one_player.name)
        print (one_player.link)



return player_list
def get_player_stats(player_list):
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    for p in player_list[0:2]:

        browser.get('https://stats.nba.com'+p.link)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

        browser.quit()
        PPG = ""
        points1 = soup.find('a',href = '/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1')
        points = points1.div
        for point in points.findNextSiblings():
            PPG = "PPG" + point.text
        RPG = ""
        rebounds1 = soup.find('a',href = '/players/traditional/?sort=REB&dir=-1')
        rebounds = rebounds1.div
        for rebound in rebounds.findNextSiblings():
            RPG = "RPG" + rebound.text

        p.PPG = PPG
        p.RPG = RPG

    browser.quit()
    return player_list
player_list = get_player_stats(get_player_list())
```

As shown in the offset code starting with `names.find_all('a'):`, everything works properly and the link gets transferred and prints out following the template(ex. Abrines, Alex   /player/203518/), but when it gets to `for p in player_list[0:2]:`, when I put in p.link, it doesn't get transferred over, and when I tried to make it print p.link, nothing got printed.  Any help would be appreciated as I've been testing out so many things for a while now!

Comment: What do you mean "transferred over"? Are you getting errors? And please fix your indentation.

Comment: Please review the question and fix the formatting.  You've got lines indented, or not indented, all over the place that are certainly wrong.

Comment: some "<a>" tags may be bookmarks or have blank href values.  (I think I saw at least one on that page that had href="".

Answer (score 0):

player_list variable is not a global variable. You define this in a single function, To keep track it in all functions, yous should initialize it globally.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first `href` in null.In that case you need to put condition before you adding this in the `list`.I have added that step now check.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
class Player():

    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.link = ""
        self.PPG = ""
        self.RPG = ""

def get_player_list():
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    browser.get('https://stats.nba.com/players/list/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    browser.quit()
    names = soup.find('div',class_='stats-player-list players-list')
    player_list = []



    for name in names.find_all('a'):
     if name["href"]:
        new_play = Player()
        new_play.name = name.text
        new_play.link = name["href"]
        player_list.append(new_play)


    # for one_player in player_list:
    #    print (one_player.name)
    #    print (one_player.link)



    return player_list
def get_player_stats(player_list):
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    for p in player_list[0:2]:
        print('https://stats.nba.com'+p.link)
        browser.get('https://stats.nba.com'+p.link)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

        browser.quit()
        PPG = ""
        points1 = soup.find('a',href = '/players/traditional/?sort=PTS&dir=-1')
        points = points1.div
        for point in points.findNextSiblings():
            PPG = "PPG" + point.text
        RPG = ""
        rebounds1 = soup.find('a',href = '/players/traditional/?sort=REB&dir=-1')
        rebounds = rebounds1.div
        for rebound in rebounds.findNextSiblings():
            RPG = "RPG" + rebound.text

        p.PPG = PPG
        p.RPG = RPG

    browser.quit()
    return player_list

player_list = get_player_stats(get_player_list())
```